# accessing objects in listview after buttonclick in listviewitem

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding

I'm trying to setup a usercontrol.

I've setup a usercontrol with a table incl table header. For each row a second usercontrol is issued displaying 1 row of the table. The line-usercontrol is embedded in a listview.

One cell of the listview contains a textbox, another cell contains a Button. The buttons for each row are using the same buttonclick event using a commandargument for finding the pressed button.

Is there somekind of way to get the value entered in the textbox of that specific line?

code header control:

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="pnlUcHeader">
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>...</th>
            ...
            <th>Textbox Column</th>
            <th>Button Column</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <asp:ListView runat="server" ID="lvUcItemsItem" OnItemDataBound="lvUcItems_ItemDataBound">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <uc1:Items runat="server" ID="ucItems" CssClass="normal" />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
</table>
```

code Item User control

```
<tr runat="server" id="serverRow">
<td>
    <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="..."></asp:Literal></td>
<td>
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tbItem"></asp:TextBox>
</td>
<td>
    <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnItem" Text="..." OnCommand="btnItem_Click"/>
</td>
```

code behind Item User control

```
protected void btnItem_Click(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    var lineID = e.CommandArgument;
    //TextBox tb = FindControl("tbAfhaalDatum)
    ???????
}
```

Is this possible in code behind or is there an option to use Javascript/Jquery to postback the value?

Kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to access your control's [`NamingContainer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.namingcontainer.aspx) to search for your text box:

```
protected void btnItem_Click(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
{
    var control = (Control)sender;
    var container = control.NamingContainer;
    var textBox = container.FindControl("tbItem") as TextBox;

    if (textBox != null)
    {
        var lineID = e.CommandArgument;
        var text = textBox.Text;
    }
}
```